# How to structure a maven project in Eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven

If I want to have a project with both EJB/JPA sourcecode and JSF in the same project how do I set up a project like that in Eclipse? I am using Maven. Is it correct on the image below? What is the difference between source folder and folder in Eclipse, and why do I have structure twice in the project below?

**GO TO** https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCmI8.png for full size picture.
[image]

Comment: Source files are listed explicitly, folder structure is listed as well--the only "difference" is that source folders are defined as such in the project settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the structure you have is a typical folder layout for a Maven webapp project. Eclipse highlights the folders containing source code that will be compiled / placed on the classpath, but also shows you the regular folders in the filesystem.

Comment: So the difference between a Source Folder and a regular Folder in Eclipse is that the Source Folder is "automatically" added to the classpath for you? Normally in Java SE when you make a new project you get one src source folder which is added to the classpath but in maven you want the test folder to be added as well so you make it a source folder? Am I right?

Comment: Yes. "Source folder" in Eclipse means "folders containing source code you want me to compile for you"